# DC/OS on top of a docker container cluster

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

Given that I have only one machine(high configuration laptop), can I run the entire DCOS on my laptop (for purely simulation/learning purpose). The way I was thinking to set this up was using some N number of docker containers (with networking enabled between them), where some of those from N would be masters, some slaves, one zookeeper maybe, and 1 container to run the scheduler/application. So basically the 1 docker container would be synonymous to a machine instance in this case. (since I don't have multiple machines and using multiple VMs on one machine would be an overkill)

Has this been already done, so that I can straight try it out or am I completely missing something here with regards to understanding?

Comment: Yes, we've done it here at Mesosphere. I'll highlight this question with the engineer who did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're running such a development configuration where ZooKeeper, Mesos Masters and Slaves as well as Marathon runs fully dockerized (but on 3 bare metal machine cluster) on CoreOS latest stable. It has some known downsides, like when a slave dies the running tasks cannot be recovered AFAIK by the restarted slave.

I think it also depends on the OS what you're running on your laptop. If it's non-Windows, you should normally be fine. If your system supports `systemd`, then you can have a look at [tobilg/coreos-setup](https://github.com/tobilg/coreos-setup) to see how I start the Mesos services via Docker.

Still, I would recommend to use a Vagrant/VirtualBox solution if you just want to test how Mesos works/"feels"... Those will probably save you some headaches compared to a "from scratch" solution. The [tobilg/coreos-mesos-cluster](https://github.com/tobilg/coreos-mesos-cluster) project runs the services via Docker on CoreOS within Vagrant.

Also, you can have a look at [dharmeshkakadia/awesome-mesos](https://github.com/dharmeshkakadia/awesome-mesos) and especially the [Vagrant based setup section](https://github.com/dharmeshkakadia/awesome-mesos#vagrant-based-setups) to get some references.

Comment: Agreed re Vagrant and also to note that we maintain a DC/OS Vagrant here: https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/local/

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Nice! You shoud add that to `dharmeshkakadia/awesome-mesos` list as well... AFAIK there was no official one before `dcos.io`. The installation looks rather complicated according to the [docs](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant/tree/v0.6.0) :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://github.com/dcos/dcos-docker it is quite young but enables you to do exactly what you want.

It starts a DC/OS cluster with masters and agents on a single node in docker containers.